# mysql LOAD INFILE / OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I'm trying to create a simple import/export feature for a web app using mySQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE and LOAD DATA INFILE functions.

It seems easiest to just leave the path for the outfile/infiles as the default mysql path (which I think normally goes into the mysql.ini-defined tmp directory).

To ensure no collisions with existing exports, I generate an MD5 of a timestamp as a prefix that I append to the OUTFILE:

```
$this->prefix = md5(time());

SELECT * INTO OUTFILE ' . $this->prefix . '-' . $table . '.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
FROM " . $table . " WHERE 1
```

So far so good, my log files show the created csv file in `/var/lib/mysql/master/`

When the script tries to do the `LOAD DATA INFILE` however, the file is not found:

```
2011-06-17 14:31:35 - INFO  --> Created outfile: eae77f210684ba0616c773677f707513-table.csv 
2011-06-17 14:31:35 - ERROR --> mySQL Error: 2 - File 'eae77f210684ba0616c773677f707513-table.csv' not found (Errcode: 2)
```

Is it possible that the `LOAD INFILE` and `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` are using different default locations?

EDIT TO ADD: I went ahead and specified the mysql tmp dir in the LOAD INFILE command-- it doesn't find the file, for some reason, even though it's clearly there and I'd assume the same "user" is reading it and writing to it:

```
$ sudo find / -name '8e357dcba6557a31f9a36230c4233d1b-table.csv'
/var/lib/mysql/master/8e357dcba6557a31f9a36230c4233d1b-table.csv

2011-06-17 15:04:25 - INFO  --> Created outfile: 8e357dcba6557a31f9a36230c4233d1b-table.csv
2011-06-17 15:04:25 - ERROR --> mySQL Error: 13 - File '/var/lib/mysql/master/8e357dcba6557a31f9a36230c4233d1b-table.csv' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

EDIT: ADDING INFILE statement

```
$this->prefix = md5(time());
$this->mysql_dir = "/var/lib/mysql/master/";
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ' . $this->mysql_dir . $this->prefix . '-' . $table . '.csv
INTO TABLE $table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do both of your error (code) listings show `INFO --> Created outfile:` (note the **outfile** after **Created**) when you're trying to 'LOAD INFILE`? And, since you showed the SQL you're using to create OUTFILE, why are you not also showing the LOAD command?

Comment: those log entries are just my own log notes-- that's not an "official" mysql log file. It gets written when the actual OUTFILE statement returns a success code. I'll post the load infile statement.

Comment: After your edit, the problem seems pretty clear. You're creating the `OUTFILE` using `$this->prefix = md5(time());` as part of the filename. Your `LOAD INFILE` is also using `$this->prefix = md5(time());` as part of the filename; if the time has changed at all, the MD5 values won't match, and therefore neither will the `OUTFILE` and `INFILE` names.

Comment: @Ken-- thanks, but that's no the case either, since the timestamp is the same-- the class sets that timestamp/md5, then uses that to do the export/import at the same time. It doesn't run against a different version of the outfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`?

Comment: This actually was the problem-- removing the LOCAL and specifying the filesystem path did the trick. The LOCAL infile changed the path where mySQL was looking for the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think julio, the problem is with the logic and not in `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` or `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

In both your examples, where you are adding $this->prefix to the OUTFILE / INFILE statements, you are regenerating the md5() each time. Therefore, the prefix that you use in OUTFILE does not match the prefix for INFILE and hence the error.

Possible solutions:
- store the prefixes in a table that you can read from later when doing LOAD DATA INFILE
- if you are generating reports at regular times, say every hour, instead of md5(), use date-time as the prefix, e.g. 20110618_1000-table.csv.